# Autocomplete on GAE not loading JSON from search.php file

Tags: php, json, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete with remote data source work in Google App Engine.

If I configure my `app.yaml` file to load `search.php`, it returns a `JSON` response formatted like this:

```
["John Smith","Allan Jones","Tammy White"]
```

I would like to use this `JSON` response as the data source of an autocomplete on `index.php`.  When I configure `app.yaml` to load `index.php` like this:

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

and then assign `search.php` as the data source for the autocomplete like this:

```
$( function() {
  $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 3
  });
} );
```

I get no response.  I don't understand why `search.php` returns a `JSON` when called directly from `app.yaml`, but it returns nothing when used as the data source for an autocomplete.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to configure `app.yaml` to route `http://YOURAPP.appspt.com/search.php` requests to your `search.php`. If you're configuring your GAE to route `/.*` to `index.php`, your request is simply served by `index.php`, which is not what you intended for.

Comment: Thanks @KoalaYeung, your suggestion makes sense.  Now I need to figure out how to implement it.  I am unsure of how the app.yaml should look to route a specific URL to a specific php file.  I tried this: - url: /search/.*
  script: search.php

Comment: I think you can read GAE documentation for [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) for reference. If I'm correct, it is simply regular expression on `url` field with the `script` as the route target.

Comment: Good suggestion.  When in doubt - read the documentation!  Once I added this handler to serve all root-level PHP scripts, I can now see the `JSON` response coming back.  This is the handler: `- url: /([^/]+\.php)
  script: \1`